# Model Architecture Design

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I have two different model architectures, I am just curious if one would be better then the other. I have tested both and they vary in performance each time I train them, but the second model generally performs a bit better, however not a major difference.

**Question:**

Are these models going to behave or perform in a similar fashion despite having different architectures? Or is there an advantage of one over the other?

**Model 1:**

[image]

**Model 2:**

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115574/discussion-between-mxk-and-machine-apprentice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed you can have two different model architectures and they yield the similar output but that does not generalize on all the data input. For example SVM with linear kernel and logistic regression  can give you similar results. For neural network, RCNN and CNN-LSTM can too have similar results, but it depends entirely on the input. For the submitted architectures that you have provided you need to code and test them yourself.